# How to fill a datarow->ItemArray from a DataGridView?

Tags: c++, datagridview, datarow

I try to fill my `DataTable` with Values from a `DataGridView`.

Code:

```
Data::DataTable^ dataTable = gcnew Data::DataTable;
int rows = dataGridView1->RowCount;
int cols = dataGridView1->ColumnCount;
for (int iZeilen= 0; iZeilen < rows; iZeilen++ ){
    Data::DataRow^ row = dataTable->Rows->Add() ;
    row->ItemArray[dataGridView1->RowCount]; 
    for (int iSpalten= 1; iSpalten = cols; iSpalten++) {
        row->ItemArray[iSpalten] = (dataGridView1[iZeilen, iSpalten]) ; 
    }
    dataTable->Rows->Add(row);
}
```

The Compiler has no problem, but during execution there is an Exception, which says:

> Index is out of range array

In Line:

```
row->ItemArray[iSpalten] = (dataGridView1[iZeilen, iSpalten]) ;
```

Can someone tell me which array is meant?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues happening here.

1. Your nested loop will only exit if `row->ItemArray[iSpalten]` is out of range.  Otherwise it will never end because your conditional statement is an assignment: `iSpalten = cols`.  Probably a simple mistake or copy-paste error.  If dataGridView1 has more columns than rows, you would get the exact error that you have.

Example:

```
Data::DataTable^ dataTable = gcnew Data::DataTable;
int rows = dataGridView1->RowCount;                            // Let's say this is 3.
int cols = dataGridView1->ColumnCount;                         // Let's say this is 5.

for (int iZeilen= 0; iZeilen < rows; iZeilen++ )
{
    Data::DataRow^ row = dataTable->Rows->Add();
    row->ItemArray[dataGridView1->RowCount];                   // 3 items in row->ItemArray

    for (int iSpalten= 1; iSpalten = cols; iSpalten++)         // iSpalten = 5, always.
    {
        row->ItemArray[iSpalten] = (dataGridView1[iZeilen, iSpalten]); // Access row->ItemArray[5] = error, index out of range 
    }
    dataTable->Rows->Add(row);
}
```

2. Though unrelated to your runtime error, you will find your dataTable not filled as you'd like.  When accessing arrays, array[row, col] is generally correct.  But for a DataGridView it's the opposite: dgv[col, row]. So this line `row->ItemArray[iSpalten] = (dataGridView1[iZeilen, iSpalten]);` should actually be `row->ItemArray[iSpalten] = (dataGridView1[iSpalten, iZeilen]);`.  I don't know why that's the convention for dgv's, nor do I like it, but it is what it is.
3. This line `row->ItemArray[dataGridView1->RowCount];` should probably be `row->ItemArray[dataGridView1->ColumnCount];` because you are adding all the values of a single row of the dgv to a single row of the dataTable.  Which means it has an item for each column.

This should get you the results you are wanting.  Hope it helps.